# Finding $P(W\le 1)$ given moment generating function of $W$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that the moment generating function is given for a random variable $W$:`

$$M_w (t)=e^{-3t+3e^t }(0.75+0.25e^t )^4$$

The mgf seems to be a mixture of both a binomial and Poisson distribution. How would I find the probability of $P(W\le 1)$?

here is a image of the expression fully written out:
[image]

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $M_{X+Y}(t) = M_X(t) M_Y(t)$. This will help you make use of your observation about the parts of the MGF seeming familiar.

Comment: By the way, I think your exercise has a typo: it should be $e^{-3 + 3 e^t}$ (to match the Poisson MGF as you noticed) rather than $e^{-3t + 3e^t}$. An MGF must satisfy $M_W(0)=1$.

Comment: Hi @angryavian, thank you for responding! How would I go about finding the probability given a Joint MGF? I know that for a single variable case, I should identify the distribution and use CDF of the distribution to find the probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: After correcting the typo, show that $W=X+Y$ where $X \sim \text{Poisson}(3)$ and $Y \sim \text{Binomial}(4, 0.25)$ are independent. Then,
$$P(W \le 1) = P(W=0) + P(W=1) = P(X=0, Y=0) + P(X=1, Y=0) + P(X=0, Y=1).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I wish I could help to upvote you but my account is too new. May I ask how to show W=X+Y? Would it suffice to state it is a 'rule' that for the sum of two independent random variables, their MGF would be the product of their two moments?

Comment: @Sleepypiggi If you have that result at hand, you can cite it on your homework, but it is not hard to prove it for yourself.